# Oracle add 1 day to timestamp value

Tags: oracle, datetime

I want to add to a timestamp variable 1 day. How could I do it?

This is my code `dayd := dayd+ 1;`, what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamp arithmetic is different than date arithmetic.

Try:

```
dayd := dayd + interval '1' day;
```

Comment: At least in Oracle 12c plus and minus operators work with `TIMESTAMP` too. Of course there is implicit conversion involved so you loose time zone and fractions of second.

Comment: True. But instead of counting on implicit conversions and hoping that their side effects remain the same over future DB upgrades, why not just do it properly and explicitly?

Comment: It was just comment that the arithmetic is actually not different. Of course is usually better not to rely on implicit conversions.